# Hive - Create Table statement with 'select query' and 'partition by' commands

Tags: hive, hiveql, create-table, hive-partitions, hiveddl

I want to create a Partitioned Table in Hive. I know to create a table structure first with the help of "Create table ... Partitioned by" command and then insert the data into the table using "Insert Into Table" command

But what I am trying to do is to combine these two commands into a single query like below but it is throwing errors.

```
CREATE TABLE test_extract AS
SELECT 
*
FROM master_extract 
PARTITION BY (year string
,month string)
;
```

Both Year and Month are two separate columns in the master_extract table.

Is there any way to achieve something like this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible, because [**Create Table As Select (CTAS)**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS)) has restrictions:

```
The target table cannot be a partitioned table.
The target table cannot be an external table.
The target table cannot be a list bucketing table.
```

You can create table separately and then insert overwrite it.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks @leftjoin

Answer (score 3):

There has been some development since this question was originally asked and answered. As per hive [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS)): `Starting with Hive 3.2.0, CTAS statements can define a partitioning specification for the target table (HIVE-20241).`

You can also see the related ticket [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-20241). It has been resolved back in July 2018.

Therefore if your hive is of 3.2.0 or higher, then you can simply do

```
CREATE TABLE test_extract PARTITIONED BY (year string, month string) AS
SELECT 
    col1,
    col2, 
    year,
    month
FROM master_extract
```